# Country Dropdown list insert ID instead of Name(string) into Database(mysql)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

Hi all expert people out there, I'm having am an issue with my website where I have my drop down list as a POST method (for a country, state, and city) working perfectly fine except one issue which it will insert the ID into my database instead of the actual name itself.

I've got confused because it display everything fine on the web page itself (a proper name show up for an individual country, state and city.

Please help me identify where the problem should be within my code.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Here is my registration page code

```
<div>
                  <select name="country" class="country">
                  <option value="<?php echo $row['country_name'] ?>">--Select Country--</option>
                  <?php
                      $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM countries");
                      $stmt->execute();
                      while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                      {
                  ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $row['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['country_name']; ?></option>
                  <?php
                      } 
                  ?>
                  </select>

                  <select name="state" class="state">
                      <option value="<?php echo $row['state_name'] ?>">--Select State--</option>
                  </select>

                  <select name="city" class="city">
                      <option value="<?php echo $row['city_name'] ?>">--Select City--</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="registration" value="REGISTER">
                <input type="reset" value=". . . RESET . . .">
```

And here is where another code to fetch data from the following fields

Get state code

```
<?php
include('db_conn.php');
if($_POST['id'])
{
    $id=$_POST['id'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    ?><option selected="selected">--Select State--</option><?php
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['state_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['state_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Get City

```
    <?php
    include('db_conn.php');
    if($_POST['id'])
    {
        $id=$_POST['id'];

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE state_id=:id");
        $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
        ?><option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>
        <?php while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['city_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['city_name']; ?></option>
            <?php
        }
    }

?>
```

and Ajax data

```
<?php
//Include database configuration file
include('db_conn.php');

if(isset($_POST["country_id"]) && !empty($_POST["country_id"])){
    //Get all state data
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id = ".$_POST['country_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY state_name ASC");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display states list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select state</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['state_id'].'">'.$row['state_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">State not available</option>';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["state_id"]) && !empty($_POST["state_id"])){
    //Get all city data
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM cities WHERE state_id = ".$_POST['state_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY city_name ASC");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display cities list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select city</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['city_id'].'">'.$row['city_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">City not available</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you insert the the option value.

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['city_id'].'">'.$row['city_name'].'</option>';
```

in this case city_id

if you wanted the name, set it as the value:

```
 echo '<option value="'.$row['city_name'].'">'.$row['city_name'].'</option>';
```

Comment: @ftfm Hi, Thank so much for you reply, you mean I have to fix that in my Ajax file right? Sorry but im very new to this ajax and php =(